# Center scroll based on viewport insteed of container fixed sized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive

I am working on a project based on a big image (7000 X 5321). The image will be like a huge map. At the center of this map the user will have the main interest point so my aim is that once the page loads, this spot needs to be in the center of the viewport and from there, the user will scroll horizontal or vertically.

My problem is that while I can adjust the scroll position with my script I need this page to be responsive so the adjustments to center this spot needs to be done based on the window viewport and not based in the size of the image and no idea if this can be done.

In the snippet below you can see my actual code and my problem. I have centered a red square inside the container. if you check the snippet at full page in a panoramic screen the spot is centered (more or less) as I would like it but it won't work if the window width or height changes (as you can see in the small window)

Any help or idea I could work on would be greatly apreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ($('body').height() / 2 - 450)
  }, 0);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: ($('body').width() / 2 - 1000)
  }, 0);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 5321px;
  width: 7000px;
}

.contenedor-mapa {
  height: 5321px;
  width: 7000px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}

.center {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor-mapa">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do it. It was not as difficult as I thought. Diego Cesar gave me the hint I needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).resize(function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).innerHeight();

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: ($('body').height() / 2 - viewportHeight / 2)
    }, 0);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollLeft: ($('body').width() / 2 - viewportWidth / 2 )
    }, 0);
  }).resize();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 5321px;
  width: 7000px;
}

.contenedor-mapa {
  height: 5321px;
  width: 7000px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}

.center {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor-mapa">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to to it 100% with jQuery, but what you need is something like:

```js
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('body').height() / 2 - window.innerHeight / 2
  }, 0);
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $('body').width() / 2 - window.innerWidth / 2
  }, 0);
```

Comment: Not longer at work but i'ts an aproach I didn't think about. Maybe get some variables with window height and width to add as margin left and margin top as with classic css top:50% margin-top: -half container height. If no other answer I will try to work on it, Ty